# Can the probability density be defined variationally?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convex-optimization, density-function

Define a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the distribution of $X$ is dominated by the Lebesgue measure and hence admits a density (pdf) $f^*(x)$ at each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible to define $f^*$ variationally? For example, does there exist a function class $\mathcal{F}$ and a loss $L$ such that $f^* = \arg\min_{f \in \mathcal{F}} E[L\{X, f(X)\}]$? I'd prefer an (e.g.) $L$ to be as well behaved as possible.

I've searched through books and papers online and have not had any luck towards resolving my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what counts as a loss function to you (should it be symmetric in the arguments?), but what about setting $$L(a,b) = (f^* (a) -b)^2.$$ Or should L be independent of the random variable?

Comment: Hi @user159517, thanks for the question. The wikipedia page for "loss function" explains what I mean by loss function. It does not need to be symmetric in the arguments. However, crucially $L$ cannot depend on $f^*$, so e.g. $(a-b)^2$ is a valid loss but your example is not. (Certainly if $f^*$ was used in $L$ then we wouldn't have a variational characterization of $f^*$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L(a,b)=-\log b$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of probability densities.

Recall the [Cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) and [Gibbs' inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality).
\begin{align*}
f^* &= \arg \min_{f \in \mathcal{F}} H(f^*,f) \\
&= \arg \min_{f \in \mathcal{F}} E_{f^*}[- \log f] \\
&= \arg \min_{f \in \mathcal{F}} E[L(X,f(X))].
\end{align*}